# Eth::Client::ContractExecutionError - transaction underpriced

Tags: gas, gas-price, polygon, cpp-ethereum, ruby

I am using the eth gem ruby library
https://q9f.github.io/eth.rb/
to execute a function called from the ABI but it keeps getting the error transaction underpriced. I assume that it has something to do with the gas price so I set a gas price and is still giving me the error. Mind you that call functions that depending on getting information like "balanceOf" works fine.

code:

```
def self.mint(mint_address, mint_amount)
      signer = Eth::Key.new(priv: @@private_key)

      client = Eth::Client.create "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/API"
      
      contract_name = "WOW"
      wow_contract = Eth::Contract.from_abi(abi: @@abiWOW.to_json, address:  @@master_contract_address, name: contract_name)
      wow_contract.key = signer

      # Convert Gwei to Wei for the gas price. 1 Gwei = 1e9 Wei.
      gas_price = 170 * 1e9

      # Set gas_price for the contract
      wow_contract.gas_price = gas_price
      wow_contract.gas_limit = 200000

      puts "gas price: #{wow_contract.gas_price}"
           
      mint_amount_in_smallest_unit = (mint_amount.to_f * (10**18)).to_i

      tx_hash = client.transact_and_wait(wow_contract, "mint", mint_address, mint_amount_in_smallest_unit, sender_key: signer)

      if client.tx_mined?(tx_hash)
        puts "Transaction was successful!"
      else
        puts "Transaction failed!"
      end
  end
```

Error:

```
Eth::Client::ContractExecutionError - transaction underpriced
```

Other output:

```
gas price: 170000000000.0
```

The network is Polygon and the client is Alchemy.

Comment: Can it be that you have an already queued transaction that's pending? A `transaction underpriced` message would typically mean there's an already pending transaction from the account but to replace it (send a different transaction with the same nonce), you'd need to bump the gas price for the transaction above 10%.